# Python "Walk" directory, max depth

Tags: python, directory, traversal

So I have seen quite a bit written on this subject, but the answers are all over the place and I am simply looking for the most efficient way to walk through a directory with a maxdepth of 1. i.e. if given "/home/user/desktop/test/", I want to be able to manipulate and work with all of the directories within that directory, but not any lower.

I have seen people saying to use the `walklevel()` function, some trickery with `os.listdir()`, or using the `.next()` feature of `os.walk()`. What is the most Pythonic/efficient way to do this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most Pythonic and the most efficient (with regard to time) may not be the same thing, and "Pythonic" can often devolve into a matter of opinion, but the most straightforward, Pythonic way to do this *in my mind* is the following:

```
import os

def contained_dirs(dir):
    return filter(os.path.isdir,
                  [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in os.listdir(dir)])
```

This is a pretty straightforward way of getting a list of all directories directly within the target directory. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm looking for so long as the 'dir' that is returned from the filter is a full path to the directory and not just the name. Is this how it will work? I think listdir only gives you the names of the directories. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or I suppose I could just keep track of the root directory and os.path.join() it with all the dirs that are returned?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot that detail about `os.listdir()`. I've updated the answer to account for joining the directory of interest to its contents.

Comment: Awesome, I will use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the directories in a given path **and nothing else** you need to list what is the path and check when you're hitting a directory

```
top_level = '/home/user/desktop/test/'
for path in os.listdir(top_level):
    directory = os.path.join(top_level, path)
    if os.path.isdir(directory)
        do_something_with_dir(directory)
```